# How to work with SSL when integrating AGIC with AKS using Terraform?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, ingress-controller

I am trying to integrate AGIC with AKS in the following method, but using Terraform: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing

I have Terraform scripts to create Azure Application Gateway (AGW) with a basic configuration, then create AKS with the AGIC addon. After that the AGW should configure the corresponding backends, listeners and rules automatically when we create the Ingress resource with correct annotation.

In order to configure SSL, there are 2 approaches it seems:

**Method 1:**

Add SSL certs as secret in kubernetes cluster, then configure 'tls' section and proper annotatons (to pint to AGIC) in the ingress resource. That will automatically add the certificate in the listener of AGW.

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-app-ingress-tls
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: test-tls-secret
    hosts:
    - test.mydomain.com 

  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           service:
             name: hello-app-service-tls
             port:
               number: 80
         pathType: Exact
```

**Method 2:**

Convert SSL certs into pfx format, add it to the AGW directly ( with name `test-ssl-certs` ). Then mention 2 annotations in the ingress resource:
one - tell to use agic as ingress controller,
two - another annotation mentioning the certificate name that we manually added in AGW.

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "test-ssl-certs"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "test.mydomain.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world
            port:
              number: 80
```

What is the difference between these 2 methods?

In both the cases, where is the SSL termination happens -inside k8s cluster, or in azure application gateway??

Which one is the better method?

Answer (score 2):

**What is the difference between these 2 methods?**

This **force-ssl-redirect** method will route to Ingress-nginx to convert all incoming **HTTP request to Https**

```
`ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`
```

This **appgw-ssl-certificate** Initiate an interaction between Ingress and Applicaiton Gateway with certificate named "test-ssl-certs", which we manually added in Applicaiton Gateway listener.

```
 appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "test-ssl-certs"
```

**Details:**
SSL certificate reference at Applicaiton gateway
[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Reference of the same from ingress file
   [image]

**NOTE: If any Certificate name mismatch it will turn to 504 error on Applicaiton Gateway.**

***In both the cases, where is the SSL termination happens -inside k8s cluster, or in azure application gateway??  Which one is the better method?***

In My view appending certificate at ingress level is a best approach, SSL termination happens at load balancer [Application Gateway] level not at K8s.  Gateway acts as a reverse proxy, means just routing requests from clients to services